# Convert bytearray to int32

Tags: c#, python

I need advice on how to convert a GUID to a `byteArray` and then convert that to and `int`. 
In the following C# code, everything works out correctly.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var str = "6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00CF4FC964FF";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
        int result1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0); 
        Console.WriteLine(result1);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Output of this program is `909723190`.

I want to write it in python3, but the result is a completely different meaning. Python code:

```python
s = "6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00CF4FC964FF"
b = bytearray()
b.extend(map(ord,s))
int.from_bytes(b, byteorder="big")
```

Output is:

```
105437014618610837232953816530997152383565374241928549396796384452286402139811961128518
```

When `byteorder` is `"little"`:

Output:

```
136519568683984449379607243264810023036788689642677418911039528254950904268659355108918
```

Comment: I can't help you with Python, but what is the point of what you are doing there in C#? You only take the ordinal values of the characters `'6'`,`'F'`,`'9'`,`'6'` and form an integer from them. Note that 909723190 is hexadecimal 0x36394636. If you pay attention you will notice there in the hexadecimal notation that bytes forming the integer are simply the ASCII codes of  `'6'`,`'F'`,`'9'`,`'6'` in little-endian order. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) If that is indeed really what you want to do, you should be able to achieve this result simply by taking the first 4 characters from the GUID string (or rather the ordinal value of those characters) and then doing some bit-shifting to place each character value at the right bit/byte positions to produce the desired integer...

Comment: That 128-bit guid isn't going to fit into a 32-bit integer.

Comment: Would you consider just taking a hash of the guid to convert to int?

Comment: @selbie you are right, but I still can not think how to implement it on python

Comment: https://ideone.com/c6kP67

Comment: A [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is 128-bits, or 16-bytes, so asking how to convert it into a 32-bit (4-byte() integer doesn't really make sense. In hexadecimal the GUID in your question is `0x6f9619ff8b86d011b42d00cf4fc964ff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code is essentially doing is taking the first four ascii values:

"6F96" => [x36, x46, x39, x36]

And then interpeting these 4 bytes in little endian as an integer:

Hence, `0x36394636 == ‭909723190`‬

Python equivalent:

```
>>> s = "6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00CF4FC964FF"
>>> val = (ord(s[3]) << 24) | (ord(s[2]) << 16) | (ord(s[1]) << 8) | ord(s[0])
>>> val
909723190
```

Comment: Thank you, very much.  Thanks especially for the explanation